# Jetpack Compose: "Unresolved reference: BottomNavigation"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My MainActivity looks this way:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        BottomNavTheme {
            Scaffold(bottomBar = {
                BottomNavigation(
                    backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.teal_200),
                    contentColor = Color.Black
                ) {

                }
            }) {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The code should be alright, I guess. But it results in an "Unresolved reference:"-error

[image: error-message]

I have implemented that functionality in the past already. It wasn't that hard to do.

**What goes wrong here? How can the issue become fixed?**

Have there been changes? I'm using the very new Android Studio Flamingo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that:

1. You added this dependency in your app module's `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.2"
   ```
2. You imported `androidx.compose.material.BottomNavigation` in your `MainActivity.kt` file.

If you did all these steps below, the error has to be disappeared. If it is not, try to invalidate caches and restart Android Studio:

```
File -> Invalidate caches -> [Mark all options such as clear file system cache etc.] -> Invalidate & Restart
```

Comment: That has worked. Thanks a lot. But that's crazy. Each time there's a new version of Android Studio, there are problems. Thinks, which worked previously fine crash at once. Where shall someone know stuff from? That one has to add to specific library to Gradle, for getting stuff working, which worked previously out of box?

Answer (score 7):

Renamed to `NavigationBar` in m3.

For more information about the changes in the new version of the material, refer to the following link:

[Migrate from Material 2 to Material 3 in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3)

Answer (score 1):

You can currently use the BottomAppBar. This is the current one.
You can currently use the bottomappbar. This is the current one. I wrote a bottom navigation currently, I will be adding its codes

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FoodAppWithComposeTheme {
                BottomBarAnimationApp()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun BottomBarAnimationApp() {
        val bottomBarState = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

        when (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
            ScreenState.CategoryBottomItem.route -> {
                // Show BottomBar
                bottomBarState.value = true
            }

            ScreenState.HomeBottomItem.route -> {
                bottomBarState.value = true
            }

            ScreenState.CategorySearchItem.route -> {
                bottomBarState.value = true
            }

            else -> {
                bottomBarState.value = false
                //Else branch is working other states
                //"car_details" -> {
                //                // Hide BottomBar
                //                bottomBarState.value = false
                //            }
            }
        }
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                BottomBar(
                    navController = navController,
                    bottomBarState = bottomBarState
                )
            },
            content = {
                SetupNavGraph(navHostController = navController)
            })

    }

    @Composable
    fun BottomBar(navController: NavController, bottomBarState: MutableState<Boolean>) {
        val items = listOf(
            BottomBarScreen.Home,
            BottomBarScreen.Category,
            BottomBarScreen.Search,
        )
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = bottomBarState.value,
            enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
            exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
            content = {
                BottomAppBar {
                    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

                    items.forEach {
                        NavigationBarItem(
                            selected = currentRoute == it.route,
                            onClick = { navController.navigate(it.route) },
                            icon = {
                                Icon(
                                    painter = painterResource(id = it.icon),
                                    contentDescription = it.title
                                )
                            },
                            label = { Text(text = it.title) },
                        )
                    }
                }
            })
    }
Bottom Navigation State

sealed class BottomBarScreen(
    val route:String,
    val title:String,
    val icon:Int
){
    object Home : BottomBarScreen(
        route = ScreenState.HomeBottomItem.route,
        title = "Home",
        icon = R.drawable.baseline_home_24
    )
    object Category : BottomBarScreen(
        route = ScreenState.CategoryBottomItem.route,
        title = "Category",
        icon = R.drawable.baseline_category_24
    )
    object Search : BottomBarScreen(
        route = ScreenState.CategorySearchItem.route,
        title = "Search",
        icon = R.drawable.baseline_search_24
    )
}
```